# Clientwidth and offsetwidth are not being calculated correctly

Tags: javascript, html, width

Im trying to calculate width of a div using pure javascript and jquery but both are showing wrong value

here is the page where it is happening

http://www.owlreporter.com/google/1153.html

just check below the heading of the article, how can i get the actual rendered width ? please check if your answer is working before posting
im very new to stack overflow and im using an iPad to post this question

```
<div style="display: block;" id="random"></div>
<script>
        adUnit   = document.getElementById("random");
        adWidth  = adUnit.clientWidth;
document.write(jQuery('#random').width());
document.write(adWidth);
</script>
```

Comment: I got 696px, and it's correct. What value are you getting?

Comment: Generally the width of the window scrollbar is deducted from the total width of the document

Comment: here is the image both showing 1024 im using an iPad http://cl.ly/093a342e3C2q       im very sure its not 1024 its the total width

Comment: what makes you say it is wrong?

Comment: ipad screen size is 768 x 1024 (Retina) the so the available div width will be less than 724 because of the sidebar

Comment: i think the problem is the style.css loading after the javascript execution